# array.insert won't save elements

Tags: ios, arrays, swift3

I'm a beginner in Swift and creating the Tictactoe game as a part of practices. I'm trying to create an empty array with 9 elements in order to track the results of the game. I'm using .insert method to fill up corresponding elements. However the array won't save the previous elements and keep updating its self from initial array every time a player taps a button. (Oh gosh I'm really bad at explaining stuff in writing)

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var cross = false



    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

        var resultArray = [String!](repeating: nil, count:9)

        let button = sender

       var index = button.tag

        if cross{

            button.setImage(UIImage(named: "cross.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)

            resultArray.insert("cross", at: index)

            resultArray.remove(at: index+1)

            cross = false
        }

        else{

            button.setImage(UIImage(named: "nought.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)

            resultArray.insert("nought", at: index)

            resultArray.remove(at: index+1)

            cross = true
        }


        print(resultArray)


    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

[And here is what I get when running the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Q9q1.png)

Comment: Is this and English paper? why the double spacing? :p

Comment: you can simplify this all quite a bit: http://pastebin.com/YvFyLJRq

Comment: an English paper* :p . Yes you're right your code makes a lot more sense than mine. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Which line would you like me to explain?

Comment: Could you explain a bit on this line: let imageName = cross ? "cross" : "nought" . I understand what it does but I didn't know I could declare a variable like this. what's this declaration method called? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's called the conditional operator: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID76

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are resetting your array on each button press, move

```
var resultArray = [String!](repeating: nil, count:9)
```

out of the function so that it is defined at the class level so it wont be reset each time.

Comment: Why did not I see that my self? I feel stupid now. Thanks for the help you're awesome!

Comment: hehe, gotta make the mistake a couple times, then you will remember to look out for it, hence ive made this mistake many times when i started programming :P